# SQL Server Agent Cannot Access Website Cookies in IE

Tags: cookies, webbrowser-control, sql-job

We have a .NET console application which has a class which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.  The program is designed to navigate to a certain URL programmatically (in a headless fashion).  It works without issue when the program is invoked from the command line.  However, when the program is run from a SQL Server job, while the web page itself *is* reachable, the site's HTML returns, "Please Enable Cookies to Continue".  Why would cookies not be enabled when being called from a SQL job but work fine otherwise?  Both runs are done under the same user account (which happens to have local Admin rights).  Furthermore, if cookies are in fact disabled, how can I enable them?

Thanks,